# Migrating hibernate 3.6 to 5.1 generates exception in HibernateUtils

Tags: java, hibernate

**My hibernate version was woefully outdated it was 3.1 and I migrated to 3.6 which works perfect and I was trying to migrate to 5.1 from
3.6.However i am having trouble in my HibernateUtils, with couple of "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems"**Here is a piece from my HibernateUtil

```
public static void beginTransaction(boolean readOnly) throws InfrastructureException {
    try {
        if( currentConnectionMode == ConnectionMode.MASTER_SLAVE && readOnly ) {
            // it is a readOnly tx
            Transaction tx = readOnlyThreadTransaction.get();
            if (null == tx || tx.wasCommitted() || tx.wasRolledBack()) {
                tx = getReadOnlySession().beginTransaction();
                readOnlyThreadTransaction.set(tx);
            }
        } else {
            Transaction tx = threadTransaction.get();
            if (null == tx || tx.wasCommitted() || tx.wasRolledBack()) {
                tx = getSession().beginTransaction();
                threadTransaction.set(tx);
            }
        } // end if
    }
```

Here is my stacktrace

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:     The method
>   wasCommitted() is undefined for the type Transaction  The method
>   wasRolledBack() is undefined for the type Transaction     The method
>   wasCommitted() is undefined for the type Transaction  The method
>   wasRolledBack() is undefined for the type Transaction
>
> at
>   wadetech.DB.base.HibernateUtils.beginTransaction(HibernateUtils.java:389)
>     at
>   wadetech.DB.base.HibernateUtils.beginTransaction(HibernateUtils.java:376)
>     at wadetech.DB.base.BaseDAO.(BaseDAO.java:43)     at
>   wadetech.DB.DAOS.__MaintenanceDAO.(__MaintenanceDAO.java:10)    at
>   com.at.project.utils.runtime.RuntimeModifier.HasExecuted(RuntimeModifier.java:127)
>     at
>   wadetech.listeners.ModificationScriptStartupListener.contextInitialized(ModificationScriptStartupListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Methods were removed after 4.3.1 in version 5.0, new call is to use getStatus.

Comment: That was a perfect shot for me.Thank you very much..!!