# Updating to Hibernate 5.1 ends up with Transaction issues

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, pom.xml, conflict

I had an issue with Transaction which is mentioned here [Migrating hibernate 3.6 to 5.1 generates exception in HibernateUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279329/migrating-hibernate-3-6-to-5-1-generates-exception-in-hibernateutils) I got a solution from that link and after doing like that I dont have anymore errors on my frame work.However I have build issues which is dragging me for two days.

I will provide my edited code which removes errors from console.

```
                TransactionStatus transactionStatus = getSession().getTransaction().getStatus();
                if (null == tx || transactionStatus.equals(TransactionStatus.COMMITTED) ||transactionStatus.equals(TransactionStatus.ROLLED_BACK)) {
                    tx = getReadOnlySession().beginTransaction();
                    readOnlyThreadTransaction.set(tx);
                }
```

And my console showing the following stack trace, I searched on web but I dint find any help that solved this issue.Please shed some light on this.Thank you

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class wadetech.listeners.ModificationScriptStartupListener
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Transaction.getStatus()Lorg/hibernate/resource/transaction/spi/TransactionStatus;
>       at wadetech.DB.base.HibernateUtils.beginTransaction(HibernateUtils.java:423)
>       at wadetech.DB.base.HibernateUtils.beginTransaction(HibernateUtils.java:399)

Comment: Are you sure this is a compile-time error? this looks an awful lot like a runtime exception to me.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I edited my question and my code.